# ng: error in production with Cb(...).firestore is not a function

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem when I use a production mode with firestore.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cb(...).firestore is
>   not a function TypeError: Cb(...).firestore is not a function

when I am serving in dev mode everything works fine.

I am using `"@angular/fire": "^5.2.1","firebase": "^6.2.3"`,

my environment is the same in dev and prod jst production is true.

When I do `ng build`  without `--prod` it works fine
when I do `ng build --prod` the error occurs.
The firebase was working properly than I added fire/storage  with some image manipulation

I really don't know which part of code to show. Because I don't know where can be the problem. :-(

```
TypeError: Cb(...).firestore is not a function
TypeError: Cb(...).firestore is not a function
    at firestore.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:39
    at e.invoke (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:391)
    at t.run (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:150)
    at t.runOutsideAngular (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:17257)
    at new t (firestore.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:37)
    at core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:21272
    at Ki (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:21234)
    at Wi (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:21198)
    at core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:21266
    at Ki (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:21234)
    at P (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:831)
    at P (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:788)
    at zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:892
    at e.invokeTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:17289)
    at e.invokeTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:422)
    at t.runTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:195)
    at g (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:601)
vn @ core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:15723
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue with AngularFirestore (working in dev, not working in prod), even though it was in the app.module.ts->@NgModule->providers.
Turns out a respective AngularFirestoreModule must be in @NgModule->imports.

Comment: You honestly saved my day.
Why is it so hard to display helpful error messages?

Comment: Thank you! I've been struggling with this for a while.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I didn`t add angularfirestorage to app.module.
I dont know why it made problems just in production but that was it.

Comment: You need to import "AngularFirestoreModule" too in imports array in case.